# How to Omit "NA"s When Converting R Dataframe to Named List

Tags: r, is-empty

I have a dataframe that's structured somewhat like this:

```
a b c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3
4
```

I would like to convert it into a named list that looks as follows:

```
Name:   Value:
a       1, 2, 3, 4
b       1, 2, 3
c       1, 2
```

However, what I'm currently getting is:

```
Name:   Value:
a       1, 2, 3, 4
b       1, 2, 3, NA
c       1, 2, NA, NA
```

As you can see, blank spaces are being filled with NAs, and I would like to avoid that, if possible.  For reference, the code I'm using to perform this transformation is simply:

```
myNamedList <- as.list(myDataframe)
```

If there's no way to prevent NAs from being added, is there a function to remove them from the resulting named list?  Many thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: In a data.frame, all vectors are of the same length. So, if you transform your named list to a data.frame, there will be NA values if one of the vectors was short. Once you transform it back to a named list, you can remove the NA from each vector, again.

Comment: Basically, the structure of the data.frame you describe first, isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.frame` is a `list` so you can use `na.omit` with `lapply` like this

```r
# create the data in the example
myDataframe <- data.frame(
  a = 1:4, b = c(1:3, NA_integer_), c = c(1:2, NA_integer_, NA_integer_))

# convert to list and remove the NAs
myNamedList <- lapply(myDataframe, na.omit)

# show the result
myNamedList
#R> List of 3
#R>  $ a: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#R>  $ b: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#R>   ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' int 4
#R>  $ c: int [1:2] 1 2
#R>   ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' int [1:2] 3 4

# you can remove attributes if you want as follows
lapply(myNamedList, c)
#R> List of 3
#R>  $ a: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#R>  $ b: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#R>  $ c: int [1:2] 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, the result of `as.list` will be a list of vectors of equal length (the number of rows of the dataframe), but you could remove the NAs from the list :

```
myNamedList <- as.list(myDataframe)
lapply(myNamedList,function(v){v[!is.na(v)]})
```